Change filesrc of a WebRTC Gstreamer pipeline
I’m using the webRTC bin from Gstreamer to stream some video (mp4) files.
I’m using a pipeline like this.
pipeline = '''
webrtcbin name=sendrecv bundle-policy=max-bundle  splitfilesrc location={} ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=-1 ! queue ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! sendrecv.
'''
Here I switched to splitfilesrc because it can change the source file dynamically. But unfortunately when I run the webrtc application, when I try to dynamically change the splitfilesrc location to something else I can see that element’s location changes but nothing happens in the webRTC stream. WebRTC stream seems to be frozen.
What could be the issue here? Can I keep the webRTC connection open and change the file source like this?
Are there any alternative methods to this?
